# Method for proving the functional completeness of connective sets

Tags: logic

I've read that when dealing with sets of connectives, one approach to proving the functional completeness is taking an already known functionally complete set, i.e {$\land,\lor,\neg$} and try to express a given set,{$\rightarrow,\lor,F$} using the given f.c. one. However, I don't understand what it actually means for a set to be functionally complete, why {$\land,\lor,\neg$} is even complete at all and how one can prove/disprove the completeness of any set. Thanks in advance for any tips or pointers.

Comment: See [Functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

Comment: See also the post [Prove-that-a-set-of-connectives-is-inadequate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191146/prove-that-a-set-of-connectives-is-inadequate).