# Logic Pure Subset Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

for example if we define :

$$ \$(p,q,r) = (p\to q)\land(\neg p\to r)$$

how we can inference that set $\{\$,\top,\bot\}$ is Full Functional and not any pure subset of this be full functional.

Comment: Are you asking how to check whether $\{\$,\top,\bot\}$ is a logically complete set of connectives? Have you written down a truth table for $\$$ and understood what it does?

Comment: yes. you are right.

Comment: And you're also asking how to verify that there's not any proper subset of $\{\$,\top,\bot\}$ that is complete?

Comment: yes, again you are right.

Answer (score 1):

For some general remarks on how to prove that sets of connectives are/are not complete, see [How to prove that a set of logical connectives is functionally complete(incomplete)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278759/)

In this particular case, it is fairly easy to figure out how to build $\vee$ and $\neg$ out of $\{\$,\top,\bot\}$, once you see that $\$(p,q,r)$ equals $q$ if $p$ is true and $r$ otherwise.

On the other hand, to see that there is no complete proper subset, it is enough to see that every subset with just one connective removed is incomplete.

For example, one can see that every expression built from $\{\$,\top\}$ alone has the property that it evaluates to true when all inputs are true, so in particular $\neg$ cannot be realized. The cases for $\{\$,\bot\}$ and $\{\top,\bot\}$ are similarly simple.

Comment: sorry for my basic English problem. "out of" means using that set?

Comment: @OpiijasFuchis: Yes. (It is not a technical term).