# Is it possible to derive all the other boolean functions by taking other primitives different of $NAND$?

Tags: reference-request, logic, boolean-algebra

I was reading the TECS book *(The Elements of Computing Systems)*, in the book, we start to build the other logical gates with a single primitive logical gate, the $NAND$ gate. With it, we could easily make the $NOT$ gate, then the $AND$ gate and then the $OR$ gate.

With the $NOT$, $AND$ and $OR$ gates, we could express any truth table through [cannonical representation](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=THie6tt-2z8C&lpg=PA1&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false).

The book has the table given below, I was wondering if we could do the same by taking any other boolean function as primitive, I'm quite sure that it's not possible to do with both constant $0$ nor constant $1$. What about the others?

[image]

Comment: [Relevant: Finding expressively adequate boolean functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126043/finding-expressively-adequate-truth-functions/207783)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question concerned arbitrary ($n$-ary) boolean functions, yet you seemed to have restricted your search to $0$-ary, $1$-ary and $2$-ary functions. A collection $C$ of boolean functions that can generate all the others by composition is called *functionally complete*, and when $C$ is a singleton $\{f\}$ we call such $f$ a *Sheffer function*. Now, a full characterization of functionally complete collections of boolean functions was given in "[The Two-Valued Iterative Systems of Mathematical Logic](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691095707/the-two-valued-iterative-systems-of-mathematical-logic-am-5-volume-5)" (Post 1941). As this book is hardly legible, though, I would heartily recommend the explanation of the main theorem in "[Post's functional completeness theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-31/issue-3/Posts-functional-completeness-theorem/10.1305/ndjfl/1093635508.full)" instead. In "Composition and clones of Boolean functions", by Pöschel and Rosenberg (first chapter of [Boolean Models and Methods in Mathematics, Computer Science, and Engineering](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/optimization-or-and-risk/boolean-models-and-methods-mathematics-computer-science-and-engineering?format=HB&isbn=9780521847520)), the exact number of $n$-ary Sheffer functions is determined: $2^{2^n - 2} - 2^{2^{n - 1} - 1}$. So, if you go beyond the $2$ binary functions NAND and NOR you should find $56$ functionally complete ternary functions, $16\,256$ functionally complete quaternary functions, and so on.

Answer (score 8):

As you noted, it's impossible for the constants to generate all of the boolean functions; the gates which are functions of a single input also can't do it, for equally-obvious reasons (it's impossible to generate the boolean function $f(x,y)=y$ from either $f_1(x,y)=x$ or $f_2(x,y)=\bar{x}$).

OR and AND can't do it either, for a slightly more complicated reason — it's impossible to generate nothing from something!  (More specifically, neither one of them is able to represent negation, and in particular neither one can represent a constant function — this is because any function composed of only ORs and ANDs will always return 0 when its inputs are all-0s and will return 1 when its inputs are all-1s.

XOR is a bit more complicated: it's obviously possible to generate 0 and 1 via XORs, and thus NOT; but the 'parity preserving' nature of XOR makes it impossible to represent $x\wedge y$ with XOR alone.

In fact, it can be shown that NOR and NAND are the only two-input boolean functions which suffice in and of themselves; for more details, have a look at the Wikipedia page on [*functional completeness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).