# Are there impossible boolean constructions?

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry, boolean-algebra, geometric-construction

I was reading about logic and I remember, for example: That with the binary $\mathtt{NAND}$  connector can be used to assemble all the other binary connectors - [I already know that there are primitive $n$-ary connectors that could be used to assemble all the other connectors.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/415152/25805) This single *tool* is used to assemble all the other connectors.

In euclidean geometry, there are two tools, compass and straitedge which are used to make some possible constructions. Thinking about both I asked myself if it would make any sense of talking about boolean constructions, if there are constructions that are not  possible to be made with the given boolean tools.

Although I have no idea of what such construction could be - which in the case of euclidean geometry there are some easy *imagineable* examples, for example: The quadrature of the circle - I don't know if someone has already thought about such objects.

I recognize that the question may be an exploration into vague and poorly defined ideas, but I'll be a lot happy for some feedback on it.

Comment: For example it is not possible to create a non-monotonic function with only monotonic operators (e.g. $\mathtt{AND}$ and $\mathtt{OR}$ are monotonic, $\mathtt{NOT}$, $\mathtt{XOR}$, $\mathtt{NAND}$ are not).

Comment: @dtldarek Thanks for the information. I'll read about it. I loved the `\mathtt{}`!